# Is there any religious exemption to EEOC-1 reporting requirements?

Tags: employment, religion, illinois

I work for a church and school. We have just over 100 employees that work for a NFP integrated auxiliary of the church. The church and the auxiliary both are 501 c 3 with separate FEIN. Is the auxiliary required to comply with EEOC-1 reporting. We are in illinois

Comment: Does your organization object on religious grounds to filing EEO-1 reports? I'm not sure if there are religious exemptions available, but if so, it's likely they only apply in the scenario of "we have a religious conviction that it would be wrong for us to do this," not just "we don't want to do this for a non-religious reason and want to get out of it with a religious exemption."

Comment: Please expand all abbreviation in this question.

Comment: This does not ask for legal advice, ande should not be closed on that basis. It simply asks what the law requires in a particular situation, and so is clearly on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You are required to report, see [29 CFR 1602.7-.11](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-29/subtitle-B/chapter-XIV/part-1602/subpart-B), unless you are not an "[employer that is subject to title VII of the Civil Rights Act of 1964](https://www.eeoc.gov/statutes/title-vii-civil-rights-act-1964)". [42 USC 2000e-1(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/2000e-1) states that

> This subchapter shall not apply to an employer with respect to the
> employment of aliens outside any State, or to a religious corporation,
> association, educational institution, or society with respect to the
> employment of individuals of a particular religion to perform work
> connected with the carrying on by such corporation, association,
> educational institution, or society of its activities.

The scope of Title VII is broader, including race, color, sex, or national origin. Thus you are in part subject to the title VII, so you must report.